# Error en ruta para guardar imagen en escritorio desde un controlador asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

me preguntaba si me daban una ayuda, les explico el problema.

estoy guardando imágenes en un objeto desde un formulario de asp.net pero aparte debo enviar la imagen a una carpeta en mi escritorio, pero la ruta no me funciona correctamente, ya que mi visual studio está instalado en el disco local E y donde yo lo quiero que se guarden las imágenes es en el escritorio que sería el disco local C.

Mi código funciona, pero solo si creo la carpeta adentro del proyecto.

```
            var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;

            string webRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;


            string upload = webRootPath + WC.ImagenRuta;
            string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(files[0].FileName);

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(upload, fileName + extension), FileMode.Create))
            {
                files[0].CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
```

esta es la clase donde almaceno la ruta donde quiero que se guarde

```
public static class WC
{
    //public static string ImagenRuta = @"\imagenes\tours\";

    public static string ImagenRuta = @"C:\Users\jason\Desktop\Imagenes";

}
```

como les comento el primer public funciona bien ya que es una ruta dentro del proyecto \imagenes\tours\ pero la segunda es la que quiero poner a funcionar pero no me sirve.

les adjunto link del error que me aparece porque no me deja subir la foto aqui

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E-wCuGeYMBF74Pi1MoHuiR1-kGk1SSUH/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reemplaza:

```
string upload = webRootPath + WC.ImagenRuta;
```

Por:

```
string upload = WC.ImagenRuta;
```

De este modo, tu imagen quedará guardada en:

```
C:\Users\jason\Desktop\Imagenes
```

Comment: te lo agradesco mucho que tengas buen dia

Comment: ¡Un gusto colaborar, éxitos con el desarrollo hermano! :D